# Get Product ID on AJAX call

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I am trying to get the current product ID (if is a product page) in this AJAX call. I have attempted to use `global $product` but couldn't make it work. Is there any way to access the current product (post) in an AJAX call?

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_product_list', 'get_product_list');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_product_list', 'get_product_list');
function get_product_list()
{

    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby'        => 'name',
        'order'          => 'ASC'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    $allProducts = '';


    //if the product page get the current product ID

    // Do something here with the current product ID


    foreach ($loop->posts as $product) {
        $allProducts = $allProducts . '<option value="' . $product->ID . '">' . $product->post_title . '</option>';
    }

    wp_reset_query();

    echo $allProducts;
    wp_die();
}
```

AJAX call

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var data = {
            'action': 'get_product_list',
        };

        jQuery.post("/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
    
        });
    });
```

Comment: get_queried_object_id() will return current ID. Just check if you are on product page using is_product() and u will know for sure this ID is product ID. I dont understand why would you query all products on product page but w/e.

Comment: @MartinMirchev Thanks. I have a review form and want it to have the `select` field to default to the current product. The `get_queried_object_id()` is returning `0`, not working.